# How to get button Id and the field name in gridviewc

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which I'm creating `dynamic` controls for each column.

For ex:

```
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
       Name | Column 1 | Column 2|
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
    Country |  LB      |  LB     |
            |          |         |
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
     City   |  LB      |  LB     |
            |          |         |
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Note**: LB refers to Link Button

I'm generating the buttons as follows in `RowCreated` Event

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
{
   LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
   lb.Click += btnForTvDisplay_Click;
   lb.ID = lb + i;
   lb.Text = "Save";
   e.Row.Cells[rowIndex].Controls.Add(btnForTvDisplay);
}
```

On the click event is there any way to find out the `Name` and the `link button Id` of that particular instance

```
void lb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //what to do to retrieve values
}
```

I mean if I click the LB of first row and first column I want to get the LB `Id` and the `name` i.e., **Country**

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
{
   LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
   lb.Click += btnForTvDisplay_Click;
   lb.ID = lb + i;
   lb.CommandName="Name";
   lb.CommandArgument=i;
   lb.Text = "Save";
   e.Row.Cells[rowIndex].Controls.Add(btnForTvDisplay);
}
```

And in `Click` Event:

```
void btnForTvDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      LinkButton bt= sender as LinkButton ;
      string name=bt.CommandName;
     string id=bt.CommandArgument;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert the sender object to a button type and get the values:

```
void lb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Button bt= sender as Button;
      string id=bt.Id;
     string text=bt.Text;
       //get more information...
 }
```

Comment: Is there a property `Name`?

Comment: @Slashy there is no property by `Name` for button

Comment: @Learner oh... i just used windows forms... my mistake.. is there a `ID` property?

Comment: Yes there is ID property

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question the OP also wants the name

Comment: @Izzy but there is'nt name property.. even in the creation of the button.. what's wrong here? he got the id, he can get the `Text` property..

Comment: Well, maybe you should explain that in your answer rather than in the comments. Btw it's `ID` not Id

Comment: @Slashy I even want the `Name`

Comment: @Learner but there is no name property at all! even when you create the button you cant specifiy a name because as you said-there's no `Name` property on .net for buttons!

Comment: @Learner why would you need that ?

Comment: @Slashy  I have to perform some maipulations with that

Comment: @Learner wouldnt you like to use another property for that? text ? or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a rowcommand button for the grid view.
Please refer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/564619/Example-of-gridview-rowcommand-on-Button-Click)

and you can get all the expected values in RowCommand Event

```
protected void gridMembersList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

 {
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void grd1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtTaskName");
            DropDownList ddlTaskStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlTaskStatus");
            Label lblSerialNoCat1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSerialNoCat1");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some explanations would significantly improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {

 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {

    Label lbl_ID = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_ID");
    string Id = lbl_ID.Text.Trim();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some details/context about how this solve the problem ?